# how to click every link using webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver

I need help in clicking each and every link that has been listed under a main menu. I was able to list them using list method. Now I want to click the link as they are being listed and if they open a new window get the URL title and navigate back to current URL. Again list the next link and click. 
 I tried the below code, but it isn't working for me:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.navigate().to(myurl);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(mylinkText));

element.click();

System.out.println(element.getText());

WebElement elements = driver.findElement(By.linkText(mylinkText2));

String text123 =elements.getText();

List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(mytagname));

    String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];
int i =0;    

for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
            linkTexts[i] = e.getText();

          System.out.println("sub menus listed under mylinkText" +  linkTexts[i]);

      WebElement tag = driver.findElement(By.tagName(mytagname2));
      Thread.sleep(1000);

     tag.click();
     // driver.navigate().to(linkTexts[i]);

      Thread.sleep(1000);


      System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

      driver.navigate().back();
               Thread.sleep(1000);

       if(linkTexts[i].equals(text123)){
    break;
       }i++;
```

Comment: Could you add a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to automate the following site menu- http://www.telerik.com/

[image: Telerik Menu]
You can use the following code to do the desired behavior.

```
[TestClass]
public class MenuLinkTests
{
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public WebDriverWait Wait { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        this.Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.Wait = new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        this.Driver.Quit();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ClickEveryHrefMenu()
    {
        this.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.telerik.com/");
        // get the menu div
        var menuList = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("GeneralContent_T73A12E0A142_Col01"));
        // get all links from the menu div
        var menuHrefs = menuList.FindElements(By.ClassName("Bar-menu-link"));

        // Now start clicking and navigating back
        foreach (var currentHref in menuHrefs)
        {
            this.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.telerik.com/");
            currentHref.Click();
            string currentElementHref = currentHref.GetAttribute("href");
            Assert.IsTrue(this.Driver.Url.Contains(currentElementHref));
            // Now the same will happen for the next href
        }
    }
}
```

The code is in C# but it is almost the same in Java.

Comment: can you be more specific and provide more feedback what doesn't work?

Comment: I used WebElement in place of var. It says  "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: I tried your exact code for telerik.com with changes for WebDriver. I am getting the above error

Comment: Just try to understand and apply the idea, don't just copy the code and expect that someone else is going to write your code every time. Tell me if you think that the idea is applicable in your case. :)

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say- I tried your code to execute the url telerik.com just to check if that works fine for Webdriver. You can see my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is find all links inside of some div

so you need to use some xpath like this:

```
var menuHrefs = menuList.FindElements(By.Xpath(".//div[@id='idOfTheDivWithLinks']/*/a"));
```

and click on them using some loop:

```
foreach (elem in menuHrefs )
{
    elem.click();
}
```

but if you click -- its will refresh the page. so you need to open links in new tabs like this:

```
Actions newTab = new Actions(getMyDriver());
newTab.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```